# Android OS update - Directly or step-by-step?

Tags: updates

I'm about to buy my first smartphone ( I've chosen Nexus 5 ), and I don't really know much about Android.
Nexus 5 comes with Android KitKat 4.4, and from what I read, the newest version is 4.4.3.
Now my question : do I have to first update to 4.4.1, then 4.4.2, and then finally 4.4.3 , or can I just directly update to 4.4.3 ?

Also, though a bit unrelated, is the mm-qcamera-daemon issue present in all versions, or just in the latest versions ?

Thanks.

Comment: The question-and-answer format of this site works best if you put each question in a separate question post. Please [edit] your post down to one question, and create new posts to ask any further questions. You'll get better answers that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update is cumulative , it will directly be upgraded to 4.4.3
Unfortunately the latest update doesn't address that bug.[Source](http://www.zdnet.com/android-4-4-3-update-rolling-out-to-nexus-motorola-and-play-devices-now-7000030212/)